# BeautifulSoupを使って<li>の内容をリストとして保存する方法？

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

次のようなtagの、liの内容の一つづつを、listとして保存したいと考えています。

```
<ul id="front">
<li class="icon-01">乗用車</li>
<li class="icon-02">トラック</li>
<li class="icon-11">軽自動車</li>
</ul>
```

現在、次のようなコードを書いています。

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd # pandas

resp = requests.get(url)
html = resp.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

icon_part = soup.find_all("ul", id = "front")
```

これにより、ulの部分を取ることが出来るが、要素一つのlistとなります。

```
[<ul id="front">
<li class="icon-01">乗用車</li>
<li class="icon-02">トラック</li>
<li class="icon-11">軽自動車</li>
</ul>]
```

liの内容が、次のようにlistの要素となるようにしたいのですが、
どうすれば良いのでしょうか？
['乗用車', 'トラック', '軽自動車']

listの中身をsplitとしようとして 次のようにも書いてみました。

```
icon_part[0].str.split('</li>', expand=True)
```

しかし、次のようなエラーが出てきます。

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd # pandas


def main():
    html ="""
    <ul id="front">
        <li class="icon-01">乗用車</li>
        <li class="icon-02">トラック</li>
        <li class="icon-11">軽自動車</li>
        </ul>
    """
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    icon_part = soup.find_all("ul", id="front")
    car_model = []
    for ul_tag in icon_part:
        for li in ul_tag.find_all('li'):
            car_model.append(li.text)
    print(car_model)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ご回答頂き、お礼申し上げます。ul_tagの使用法を知ることができました。